# For what reasons could a PR number not be present in a PR event?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions script where one step is as such:

```
steps:
    - name: View the PR number
      run: |
        echo "PR number = ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}"
        echo "PR number2 = ${{ github.event.issue.number }}"
      shell: bash
```

These variables are apparently empty since after the equals sign nothing is printed. According to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request this ought to work, however.

But to my surprise, neither gives a PR number. What reason there could be?

Basically I made a branch to my own repo, pushed it and opened a PR. I modified the action file within that PR. The action file in its entirery is [here](https://github.com/veikkoeeva/DotDecentralized/blob/d4cd354395923ac46a72cf8a8c42cc9d8d44d166/.github/workflows/main.yml#L46) if it matters.

Comment: Your workflow file has many trigger events. For what I saw from the Action tab history on the repository, it looks that most of them were triggered from a push event (which could explain why the pull request number is null). Could you share the workflow run initiated from a pull request event?

Comment: I suppose you mean https://github.com/veikkoeeva/DotDecentralized/actions/runs/1050605718 is one such run (don't mind the typo). I'm learning this as I go (and refactor the code to fit GHA better), so all suggestions and pointers are very much welcome, of course.

Comment: This one has been triggered by a push to the `testdevelop` branch. It's informed below the *workflow run title* on the link you shared.

Comment: Or, since it has a typo, I assume the branch is `testdevelo` you mean. I created this branch to create a test PR to see if that event gives a PR number. It appears that while the flow is triggered, the aforementioned events do not have a PR number. Which is puzzling to me. As far as I see, there's a branch a PR to to `develop` branch, but no PR number available in the workflow.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean, @GuiFalourd! So the PR event is available only on the initial PR, not on subsequent pushes to the branch that has PR. The PR number assoaciated with the push commit needs to be retrieved by some other mean.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Do make this an answer and I accept it! This helped me to understand wher the problem is. I checked quickly by using https://github.com/marketplace/actions/find-current-pull-request and this seem to work so that it finds the PR number also when pushing to the PR branch.

Comment: Great! Sorry for not being available the last couple of hours, but you got it right. I'll resume our discussion in an official answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that the PR number is only available on the initial PR event.

Afterwards, all your events are being triggered `by pushes` to the PR branch (as your workflow file has many trigger events) and that's the reason why the PR number is not available.

In your case, the [find-current-pull-request](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/find-current-pull-request) action could be an alternative to find the PR number when pushing to the PR branch.

Comment: How about `${{github.event.number}}` 
Would it return null for subsequent events?
What is the solution for ensuring pull request number is always returned for any kind of event on the Pull request?
@GuiFalourd

Comment: If you check the [PR event context json](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/e53ec9b6bc783cce184bd1eec263799d) you'll see the `${{github.event.number}}` is available. However, the subsequent [push event context json](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/81f41fb8b53a0bd3d63856f919e501c2) doesn't have this value set, therefore it would be null. The [synchronized PR](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) event context json may have this value has well today (it wasn't available in 2021). I just don't have a json example.